# Arduino IDE "Tools > Serial Port" grayed out (Ubuntu)

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, ubuntu

I know this has been asked before, but no one's solutions I've seen have worked so far. I just got started with Arduino and downloaded Arduino IDE from the Software Center. When trying to to set up my Serial Port, the option in the toolbar is gray/unaccessible.

I also downloaded it as a tar.xz instead of from the Software Center and had the same problem.

When I plug in my Uno, the green light turns on so I know it's being connected at least.

One solution I saw said it was a problem with my user group. However, I entered

`sudo groups <username>`

and came up with `<username> tty dialout sudo audio video plugdev input`

so I think my groups are okay, right?

Anyway, I would really appreciate some help if anyone knows of a fix. I run 12.04 Ubuntu (I recently re-installed trying to fix this problem; I'm going to update to 14.04) on a Chromebook.

Comment: To investigate this, edit the output of `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` and `ls -l /dev/ttyACM*` (done while the board is connected) into your question.  Also if you recently changed any group memberships make sure you have logged out (or more simply, rebooted) since.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify? I input `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` as well as `ls -l /dev/ttyACM*` into my terminal and it simply said it was not a directory. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: If neither of those is turning up anything, then it sounds like nothing is recognizing your USB serial device.  You can look for differences in the output of `lsusb` when it is and isn't connected, or you can check for error messages shortly after connection with `demsg`.  At this point it could be anything - bad board, bad cable, damaged connector, missing kernel modules, or bad/atypical rules for udev or similar.

Comment: Within `/dev` the only "tty" files I have are "tty" and "tty8." Does it seem like I'm missing something?   EDIT: I damaged one of my USB ports last year, though I'm using the other one so I don't think it's that. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I did what  Chris Stratton's comment suggested,

> To investigate this, edit the output of ls -l /dev/ttyUSB* and ls -l /dev/ttyACM* (done while the board is connected) into your question. Also if you recently changed any group memberships make sure you have logged out (or more simply, rebooted) since.
>   If neither of those is turning up anything, then it sounds like nothing is recognizing your USB serial device. You can look for differences in the output of lsusb when it is and isn't connected, or you can check for error messages shortly after connection with demsg. At this point it could be anything - bad board, bad cable, damaged connector, missing kernel modules, or bad/atypical rules for udev or similar.

and there was no difference between the output of `lsusb` with or without the arduino in it (arduino Mega 2560, and my pc is debian 8.6). I tried it with a diffrent cable but that made no difference. I tried it with an other arduino (uno) and then I did saw differnce in `lsusb` and I could select a port. My mega had the 'on' led on. So even though lights are on and/or binking, it might be that your arduino is broken. If you can, try it with an other arduino. Otherwise you can try an other cable and usb port on your pc.